# Why can't I add a Form label to my Label list?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got this code right here and it's not really working the way it should :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    weather = new Weather();
    dynamic weatherObject = weather.refreshData();
    gui = new GUICreator(weatherObject);

    List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>();

    foreach(Control element in this.Controls)
    {
        if (element.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            labelList.Add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is mostly the loop which is supposed to populate the list with all available labels in my form in order to make it ready to be passed to some other class.

However, I always get an error at the `labelList.Add(element)` line, which is: "The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic .... has some invalid arguments".

I don't get whats going wrong here. I double checked if the element is the right type at that certain line, and it indeed always is a Label. What's wrong? I can't remember having to add another thing to a List.add except for the element which is to be added?

Comment: Have you tried to cast your `element` to `Label` instead of let it be `Control`?

Comment: You need to cast `element` to `Label` before you add it.

Comment: Oh right, I'm seriously annoyed that I spent 15 minutes trying to figure this out while just forgetting a cast... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that the compiler sees a `Control` object added to a `List<Label>`. The compiler cannot look at your code and understand from your logic that you are adding only Labels. Instead if you write

```
 foreach(var element in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
 {
     labelList.Add(element);
 }
```

now you are giving enough info to the compiler and it can understand that you are adding Labels and not generic Controls

And, as noted below from [ASh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash), if your intent is just to have a `List<Label>` without further processing then you could just write a single line

```
  List<Label> labelList = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
```

Comment: why not `List<Label> labelList = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();`?

Comment: @ASh you are absolutely correct. Given the context this is better

Answer (score 1):

This is the code behind the `List<T>.Add` method:

```
public class List<T>
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (this._size == this._items.Length)
        {
            this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
        }
        this._items[this._size++] = item;
        this._version++;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is only accepts parameters which are of the type T, which you have set when you initialized the list.

```
   List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>();
```

Now when looping through the elements you specify that the items to iterate over are of the type `Control`. In the List, `T` is not `Control`, as its of the type `Label`.

You should cast the `Control` variable (`item`) to `Label`, as [`Label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extends from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

You've to cast `element` to `Label`, to match the `List` type.

```
labelList.Add((Label) element);
```